# Docusign connect Certificate HTTPS Error

Tags: java, tomcat7, x509certificate, docusignapi

I created a listener to docusign connect to listen for status update of the envelop. I did my setup on sandbox, it all works well when I'm just using http. I found in the documentation that in production I have to use https. I'm just a newbie here sorry for this. What I did is that I downloaded the X.509 certificate of docusign, upload it in my server and run this command.

**keytool -import -alias xxx -trustcacerts -file "signedby_2016_public.cer" -keystore "/usr/xxxKeystore"**

and configure my tomcat7 like this.

```
<Connector port="443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
           maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"   keystoreFile="xxxKeyStore" keystorePass="*****"
    ciphers="TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,
        TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
        TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,
        TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA"

 />
```

But when I try to send a document the error on docusign is this.

```
Error - The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
```

And when I try to go to my tomcat home page the error is this in chrome.

```
ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH
```

I've been looking for this in a day now. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For production, your Connect Listener (which must be a service available on the internet) must accept https requests. And the url that you provide in your Connect configuration settings must specify https://your-server-name... as the url.

To accept incoming https requests (from DocuSign), your Connect Listener's web server has to be configured correctly and needs an SSL certificate. You get that certificate from any CA trusted by the usual pre-approved lists in browsers. A cheap certificate is fine (about $10 per year or lesss).

You can probably use the free [letsencrypt.org](https://letsencrypt.org/) certs. (I haven't tested this yet but it should work fine.)

If you have trouble configuring your web server to accept SSL requests, ask on the StackOverflow SuperUser list.

You do not need to download or install the DocuSign certs unless you want to check the origin of the incoming SSL connections from DocuSign.

Comment: In particular, your server must have a cert *for a privatekey you have (generate) and your domain name*. You can't use the Docusign cert for your server unless you get Docusign to also give you their privatekey, which since it is private they won't, and control of their domain which they certainly won't.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using AES 256 instead of AES 128?

Comment: Yes, didn't work. Have you work with docusign before?